# Java Matcher.replaceAll() matches group(0) elements as well

Tags: java, regex

I think this is a very common problem, but couldn't find a related question in SO or any other tutorial as well. So if it's a duplicate, feel free to mark as such.

Well here is the problem, I have a `String` and I would like to replace all the words `test` in it to `tested`. But I don't want to replace the word if it's contained inside a `<>`

**Eg:** String `this test is <other test end>` should be replaced by `this tested is <other test end>`.

So i have create a regex `(?:<.*?>)|(test)` (anything inside `<>` should be a non-capturing group and all other `test` should be match.

But as I understand `Matcher.group(0)` will match even the non-capturing group. And what's worse is `Matcher.replaceAll()` seems to replace the non-capturing group text as well?

How can I solve this? Is there any way I can specify `replaceAll()` to replace only `group(1)` elements?

Is there some other easy and clean way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead assertion.

```
string.replaceAll("test(?![^<>]*>)", "tested")
```

**Explanation:**

- `test` - Matches the string test only if it's not followed by
- Any char but not of `<` or `>`, zero or more times.
- Further followed by `>` char. So this matches all the `test` except the one present inside `<>`

Comment: That worked perfect. Thanks. But can you also explain why?? I tried this and it didn't work `test(?!<[^<>]*>)`.

Comment: you may use this `"test(?=[^<>]*(?:<|$))" also`